# Bayesian networks with continuous variables in Python

Tags: python, fitting, continuous-data, bayesian-network

I am trying to create a Bayesian network model (Probabilistic graphical model) in Python, that can handle continuous data. I have tried using pgmpy, but the 'fit' function in pgmpy has not yet been implemented for the continuous case yet, and I am trying to avoid creating this model from scratch.

Is there another Python package that can achieve this?